# making all pages start at index.cfm if session.allowin is not true

Tags: coldfusion

I am making an application in coldfusion 10 and I am trying to figure out how to make every page go to my "login page" which i have set up as index.cfm at the moment.

The url is correct no matter which page you open its defaulting me to the login page but for some reason the page is not opening correctly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**Application.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfparam name="session.allowin" default="false">
    <cfparam name="session.userid" default="0">
    <cfif session.allowin neq "true">   
          <cflocation url="index.cfm">
    </cfif>

    <cfset this.datasource = "database" >
    <cfset this.name = "ExitInterview">
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = "true">
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
    <cfset this.clientManagement = "false">
    <cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
    <cfset this.setDomainCookies = "true">
    <cfset this.scriptProtect = "true">
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
</cfcomponent>
```

[image: Browser - Page is not redirecting properly]

**Update:**
Based on the answers, here is my latest Application.cfc which is still not redirecting properly:

```
<cfcomponent
displayname="ExitInterview"
output="true"
hint="Handle the application.">


<!--- Set up the application. --->
<cfset this.datasource = "database" >
<cfset this.name = "ExitInterview">
<cfset this.sessionManagement = "true">
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
<cfset this.clientManagement = "false">
<cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
<cfset this.setDomainCookies = "true">
<cfset this.scriptProtect = "true">
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">


<!--- Define the page request properties. --->
<cfsetting
    requesttimeout="20"
    showdebugoutput="false"
    enablecfoutputonly="false"
    />


<cffunction
    name="OnApplicationStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="boolean"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the application is first created.">

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnSessionStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the session is first created.">

    <cfset session.allowin = false />
    <cfset session.userid = 0 />
    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequestStart"
    access="public"
    returntype="boolean"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires at first part of page processing.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument
        name="TargetPage"
        type="string"
        required="true"
        />

    <!---  Set an array of pages where the user does not need to be logged in. --->
    <cfset local.aNonLoggedInPages = ["index.cfm", "login_process.cfm"] />
    <cfset local.bRedirect = true />

    <!---  If you're not logged in, check if you should redirect from the currect page. --->
    <cfif !session.allowin>
        <cfloop array="#local.aNonLoggedInPages#" index="local.x">
            <cfif local.x EQ arguments.targetPage>
                <cfset local.bRedirect = false />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>

        <cfif local.bRedirect>
            <cflocation url="index.cfm" />
        </cfif>  
    </cfif>

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequest"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires after pre page processing is complete.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument
        name="TargetPage"
        type="string"
        required="true"
        />

    <!--- Include the requested page. --->
    <cfinclude template="#ARGUMENTS.TargetPage#" />

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnRequestEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires after the page processing is complete.">

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnSessionEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the session is terminated.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument
        name="SessionScope"
        type="struct"
        required="true"
        />

    <cfargument
        name="ApplicationScope"
        type="struct"
        required="false"
        default="#StructNew()#"
        />

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnApplicationEnd"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="false"
    hint="Fires when the application is terminated.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument
        name="ApplicationScope"
        type="struct"
        required="false"
        default="#StructNew()#"
        />

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>


<cffunction
    name="OnError"
    access="public"
    returntype="void"
    output="true"
    hint="Fires when an exception occures that is not caught by a try/catch.">

    <!--- Define arguments. --->
    <cfargument
        name="Exception"
        type="any"
        required="true"
        />

    <cfargument
        name="EventName"
        type="string"
        required="false"
        default=""
        />

    <!--- Return out. --->
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: so, every time you try to open index.cfm - you will be redirected to index.cfm, so you will try to open index.cfm, which will redirect you to index.cfm

Comment: lol I am trying to have it where if session.allowin is false then the user gets redirected to index.cfm if its true the page should open up as normal

Comment: session.allowin is always false, so you always redirect user, no matter which page it tries to get

Comment: Any time you do a redirect like this, you have to add an exemption for the actual page you're redirecting them to-- usually the login page.  So "if they're not logged in and not ALREADY on the login page, THEN redirect".

Comment: any chance for an example? I cant wrap my mind around this i keep messing with session.allowin but i feel like it has nothing to do with this

Comment: i tried an else that didnt work

Comment: you want something like if current page isn't login page or session.allowin neq "true" then relocate, otherwise don't ( and load login page )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest you learn more about Application.cfc:

http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/

You should set your session defaults in `onSessionStart()`, not in the root of the file.

Next, your access check should be in `onRequestStart()`. Should look something like this (untested code):

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset this.datasource = "database" >
    <cfset this.name = "ExitInterview">
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = "true">
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
    <cfset this.clientManagement = "false">
    <cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
    <cfset this.setDomainCookies = "true">
    <cfset this.scriptProtect = "true">
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onSessionStart" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
        <cfset session.allowin = false />
        <cfset session.userid = 0 />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true" />
        <!--- Set an array of pages where the user does not need to be logged in. --->
        <cfset local.aNonLoggedInPages = ["index.cfm", "login_process.cfm"] />
        <cfset local.bRedirect = true />

        <!--- If you're not logged in, check if you should redirect from the currect page. --->
        <cfif !session.allowin>
            <cfloop array="#local.aNonLoggedInPages#" index="local.x">
                <cfif local.x EQ arguments.targetPage>
                    <cfset local.bRedirct = false />
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>

            <cfif local.bRedirect>
                <cflocation url="index.cfm" />
            </cfif>  
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn true />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**EDIT:** Updated to check if you're logged in or not before checking the redirect.

**EDIT re: Comments** It's not a bad question, it's just honestly a bad approach to what you're trying to do. Imagine you've got 10 logged in pages and 20 pages where you don't need to be logged in. Then you add more pages where you don't need to be logged in. Maintaining an ever growing array of non-logged in pages is not what you want to do.

A better approach could be this:

```
\Application.cfc
\index.cfm
\about_us.cfm
\contact.cfm
\login.cfm
\login_process.cfm
\private\
\private\Application.cfc
\private\index.cfm
```

In this structure,

`\Application.cfc` is the same as above, but without the content in `onRequestStart()`.

`\private\Application.cfc` extends `\Application.cfc` and should only contain the following (notice the leading slash to refer CF to the root of the website):

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfif !session.allowin>
        <cflocation url="\index.cfm" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn true />

</cffunction>
```

Now, for any CFM page within the `\private\` folder, you have to be logged in to access it. You can have multiple folders at the same level as `\private\`, each with their own `Application.cfc` (which still extends the root one) and each with the same logged in check. You can also use them to organize session variables related to each folder's "sub application".

Comment: this is not working either I am still getting the same pop up

Comment: upvoted for helping lead me in the right direction though

Comment: maybe its this line <cfset local.bRedirct = false /> since its spelled wrong Ill try fixing that too

Comment: is this a really bad question? Im getting downvoted like crazy ... just trying to learn ...

Comment: ughhh wish it atleast gave an error instead of redirect did not work properly lol

Comment: Posted an update with a better approach to your issue.

Comment: its pretty much every page should be logged in to see if your not logged in I want them to be directly sent to index.cfm. I cant see why any page would be able to be seen without being logged in

Comment: What about the login form? the page that processes the login form?

Comment: the login form is the index.cfm

Comment: even the new edit is not working for me ... I just dont understand what I am doing wrong. Do i need to put something on all other cfms? I thought this covers all of them

Comment: @DavidBrierton - Now would be a very good time to start brushing up on troubleshooting and debugging 101 techniques. You are not always going to get copy and paste code, so it is important to understand whatever is provided, not just take it, paste it and run ;-). As mentioned, the code is *untested*. If something is slightly off, it is up to you to start debugging and try and find out what that something is.  For example, you could temporarily enable output in onRequestStart so you can view actual the values of the variables on each request (cont'd)

Comment: Then look over the simple CFIF logic and try and figure out why it is not behaving as expected with those variables. Here is a starter example http://trycf.com/gist/9ce910c226f0ad3cc6d838b8e51871d2/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: thanks @Leigh its definitely the if statement im just struggling with it like crazy thank you for the help though

Comment: yay I fixed it with writing a new if statement but if a page is higher up I cant figure out how to make it go backwards like ../index.cfm any chance you can assist?

Comment: Make what go backward? If you mean cflocation, use an absolute path, not a relative one.  Though as mentioned, this is really not a sustainable structure. See the edits in the answer above for a better alternative.